# Has any respected conservative/libertarian/Republican writer, speaker, or officeholder in any way endorsed Donald Trump as a serious candidate?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, conservatism, republican-primary

With the starting electoral debate for the 2016 USA elections Donald Trump has been high on the news. He's made many controversial statements and defies many standards of what would expected from a presidential candidate. Does he have any credibility as a serious candidate, or is he just trying to turn voters away from more left-wing candidates and cause controversy?

Comment: I think the only person that can answer this is Mr. Trump. And even then, I think we'd have to take the answer with a grain of salt.

Comment: The terse wording of the question made me chuckle, so no downvote, but this really isn't a good fit for the SE, so I do have to vote to close.

Comment: Perhaps rephrase to "Has any respected conservative/libertarian/Republican writer, speaker, or officeholder in any way endorsed Donuld Trump as a serious candidate?"

Comment: Left wing candidates?  Bernie Sanders is running as a Democrat, or are there other left wing candidates accidentally lost in the Republican primaries?

Comment: Of course, there's the inevitable accusations that Trump himself is pretty left wing, in some cases :)

Comment: This question can't be answered without precisely defining "serious" and "respected."

Comment: Some questions don't age so well....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A full list of current endorsements if available at a marginally known website known as "Wikipedia".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorsements_for_the_Republican_Party_presidential_primaries,_2016#Donald_Trump

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump_presidential_campaign,_2016#Endorsements

*(the latter seems to be a direct include from the former, unless I misunderstand how Wikipedia code works)*

---

## As-Of August 2015

Of course, the fact that the endorsements range from Charlie Sheen to Chuck Yeager, and from Dennis Rodman to Michael Savage, makes it a very difficult case to make for either of the two desired conclusions ("Trump is a clown" vs "Trump is for real").

Among people that can easily be classified as "respected conservarive or libertarian figures", we have:

- Michael Savage
- Jim Gilchrist
- Sam Nunberg
- Ted Nugent

... and if you squint hard enough at the word "respected", you can add

- Ann Coulter
- 12 State representatives from different states
- A number of people who are best classified as political operatives rather than political office holders

---

## As-of February 2016

- Chris Christie (NJ Governor and former 2016 primary candidate)
- 1 current and 2 former Governors (Paul LePage, Sarah Palin, Jan Brewer)
- 1 current and 1 former US Senator (Jeff Sessions and Scott Brown)
- 4 current and 1 former US Representatives
- 17 current and 8 former state officials or representatives
- gazillion media, cultural, business and just weird people. I don't think Tila Tequila's endorsement is a highlight :)

---

## As-of November 10, 2016

59,611,678 votes / 279 electoral votes according to Google so far. I suspect "is a clown" conclusion was somewhat proven slightly wrong.

More on-topic, Wiki page lists 39 current US senators and 10 ex-senators; 183 current House members and 23 former.

Comment: +1 I think that gives the flavor of Trump's endorsements. For people less familiar with American politics, I think a lot of American conservatives will look at that list and see further evidence for Trump being a fringe clown.

Comment: @lazarusL - eh? Since when is Michael Savage and Ted Nugent and Chuck Yeager a fringe clown material? For that matter, given the list of brainless celebrities endorsing every Democrat, even Rodman doesn't look that bad (there's no excuse for Charlie Sheen though).

Comment: I also omitted Scott Adams (as in Dilbert creator). Mostly because he's very explicitly trying to claim he's not endorsing ANYONE, right after admitting he has a politi-crush on Trump's methodology.

Comment: Certainly some number of people think these are respectable sources of political philosophy and policy; a fair number of people support trump. A lot of other conservatives (I personally hope a vast majority) see them as entertainers who take radical positions for attention and people who have the most extreme and reductionist views on immigration, a complicated issue [that conservatives are split on](http://www.nationalreview.com/article/384150/conservative-case-immigration-reform-alex-nowrasteh).

Comment: @lazarusL - oy. That link has so many fallacies I don't even know where to start.

Comment: "Since when is...Ted Nugent...a fringe clown material?" Umm...since Cat Scratch Fever? Wang Dang Sweet Puntang? :)

Comment: @lazarusL When...

Answer (score 4):

Here are 125 scholars and writers for Trump.

Charles Akeman, University of California, Santa Barbara

Jeffrey H. Anderson, Ph.D., author of “An Alternative to Obamacare” and “The Main Street Tax Plan”

Hadley Arkes, Amherst College emeritus, author of “Constitutional Illusions and Anchoring Truths: The Touchstone of the Natural Law”

Larry P. Arnn, Hillsdale College, author of “Churchill’s Trial: Winston Churchill and the Salvation of Free Government”

Stephen H. Balch, Texas Tech University, National Humanities Medal, co-author of “Western Civilization and the Academy”

Mark Bauerlein, Emory University, author of “The Digital Divide: Arguments for and Against Facebook, Google, Texting, and the Age of Social Networking”

Darren Beattie, Duke University

Roger Beckett, Ashland University

Bill Bennett, former Secretary of Education, author of “America: The Last, Best Hope”

Jay Bergman, Central CT. State University, author of “Meeting the Demands of Reason: The Life and Thought of Andrei Sakharov”

Denis Binder, S.J.D., Chapman University, author of “Can We Secure the Hallowed Elms of Academe”

Conrad Black, author of “Franklin Delano Roosevelt: Champion of Freedom”

Daniel A. Bonevac, University of Texas, author of “Deduction: Introductory Symbolic Logic

Andrew Bostom, Brown University, author of “Sharia versus Freedom”

James Bowman, Ethics and Public Policy Center, author of “Honor: A History”

F.H. Buckley, George Mason University, author of “The Way Back: Restoring the Promise of America”

Thomas E. Brennan, lawyer and former Chief Justice of the Supreme Court of Michigan

Chris Buskirk, editor and writer, American Greatness

Nicholas Capaldi, Loyola University New Orleans, co-author of “Liberty and Equality in Political Economy”

Jim Capua, Ph.D., writer

Timothy W. Caspar, Hillsdale College, author of “Recovering the Ancient View of Founding: A Commentary on Cicero’s De Legibus”

Lionel Chetwynd, Oscar and Emmy nominated producer, director, screenwriter of “Miracle on Ice” and “Hanoi Hilton”

Lynn Chu, Writers’ Representatives, LLC

Mickey Craig, Hillsdale College

Glynn Custred, CSU-Haywood emeritus, author of “A History of Anthropology as a Holistic Science”

Donn Dears, author of “Nothing to Fear”

David Deming, University of Oklahoma

Marshall DeRosa, Florida Atlantic University

Michael Doran, Hudson Institute, former senior director of the National Security Council

John C. Eastman, Chapman University Fowler School of Law and the Claremont Institute, author of “Born in the U.S.A? Reassessing Birthright Citizenship in the Wake of 9/11”

Edward Erler, CSU San Bernardino, co-author of “The Founders on Citizenship and Immigration: Principles and Challenges in America”

Clarice Feldman, lawyer and writer

Peter J. Ferrara, Heartland Institute, author of “Power to the People: The New Road to Freedom and Prosperity for the Poor, Seniors and Those Most In Need of the World’s Best Health Care”

Burton W. Folsom, Jr., Hillsdale College, co-author of “The Myth of the Robber Barons”

John Fonte, Ph.D., author of “Sovereignty or Submission”

William A. Frank, University of Dallas, author of “Duns Scotus, Metaphysician”

Neal B. Freeman, writer, businessman, Peabody Award-winning television producer

Bruce Frohnen, Ohio Northern University, author of “Constitutional Morality and the Rise of Quasi-Law” (with George W. Carey)

George Gilder, author of “Wealth and Poverty” and “The Scandal of Money: Why Wall Street Recovers But the Economy Never Does”

Callista Gingrich, co-author of “Rediscovering God in America”

Newt Gingrich, Ph.D., former Speaker of the House, co-author of “A Nation Like No Other: Why American Exceptionalism Matters”

Tom Giovanetti, writer Esther Goldberg, lawyer and writer for The American Spectator

Mary Grabar, co-author of “The Crisis in American Journalism and the Conservative Response”

Lino Graglia, University of Texas—Austin, author of “Disaster by Decree”

David P. Goldman, author of “How Civilizations Die: (And Why Islam Is Dying Too)”

Darren Guerra, Biola University, author of “Perfecting the Constitution: The Case for the Article V Amendment Process”

Susan Hanssen, University of Dallas, author of “Shall We Go to Rome?: The Last Days of Henry Adams”

Anne Hendershott, Franciscan University of Steubenville, co-author of “Renewal: How a New Generation of Faithful Priests and Bishops Is Revitalizing the Catholic Church”

Phillip Henderson, Catholic University of America, author of “Managing the Presidency: The Eisenhower Legacy”

Arthur Herman, Ph.D., author “Douglas MacArthur: American Warrior”

David Horowitz, editor and author of “The Left In Power: Clinton to Obama”

Deal Hudson, Ph.D., editor and author of “An American Conversion”

Carol Iannone, editor and writer

Christina Jeffrey, Ph.D., author of “The UN/State Department Refugee Program Comes to Spartanburg”

Douglas Jeffrey, Hillsdale College, editor of Imprimis

Marjorie Jeffrey, writer

Robert C. Jeffrey, Wofford College

Brian T. Kennedy, writer, The American Strategy Group

Jack Kerwick, Rowan College, author of “Misguided Guardians: The Conservative Case Against Neoconservatism” (forthcoming)

Charles Kesler, Claremont McKenna College, editor Claremont Review of Books, author of “I Am the Change: Barack Obama and the Future of Liberalism”

Roger Kimball, editor and author of “The Fortunes of Permanence: Culture and Anarchy in an Age of Amnesia”

Robert D. King, University of Texas—Austin, author of “Nehru and the Language Politics of India”

Michael Kochin, Tel Aviv University

Robert C. Koons, University of Texas—Austin, co-author of “Metaphysics: The Fundamentals”

E. Christian Kopff, University of Colorado Boulder, author of “Virgil and the Cyclic Epics”

Lawrence Kudlow, Co-author of “JFK and the Reagan Revolution: A Secret History of American Prosperity”

Michael Ledeen, Ph.D., co-author of NY Times best-seller “Field of Fight: How We Can Win the Global War Against Radical Islam and Its Allies”

Seth Leibsohn, radio host and co-author of “The Fight of Our Lives: Knowing the Enemy, Speaking the Truth, and Choosing to Win the War Against Radical Islam”

Thomas Lifson, Ph.D., editor and writer, American Thinker

Margaret Lindsay, Ph.D., writer

Thomas Lindsay, Ph.D., co-author of “Investigating American Democracy”

Robert Oscar Lopez, Southwestern Baptist Theological Seminary, author of “The Colorful Conservative: American Conversations with the Ancients from Wheatley to Whitman”

Herb London, Ph.D., author of “The Encyclopedia of Militant Islam”

John R. Lott, Jr., Ph.D., author of “More Guns, Less Crime”

Ted Roosevelt Malloch, Oxford University, co-author of “America’s Spiritual Capital”

Ken Masugi, Johns Hopkins University, co-author of “The Supreme Court and American Constitutionalism”

Daniel McCarthy, editor and writer, contributor to “Dilemmas of American Conservatism”

Roger Meiners, University of Texas—Arlington, author of “Gridlock in Government”

Allen Mendenhall, Faulkner University, author of “Literature and Liberty”

Tiffany Jones Miller, University of Dallas

Brian Patrick Mitchell, author of “Eight Ways to Run the Country”

Laurie Morrow, Ph.D., co-author of “Conversations on Philanthropy”

Steve Moore, co-author of “Fueling Freedom: Exposing the Mad War on Energy”

Steve Mosher, Population Research Institute

William Murchison, author of “The Cost of Liberty: The Life of John Dickinson”

Deroy Murdock, columnist and writer

Maureen Mullarkey, writer for The Federalist

George Neumayr, co-author of “No Higher Power: Obama’s War on Religious Freedom”

Marita Noon, author of “Energy Freedom”

Michael J. O’Shea, writer

Daniel Palm, Azusa Pacific University

Svetozar Pejovich, Texas A & M emeritus, author of “The Economics of Property Rights”

Ronald J. Pestritto, Hillsdale College, author of “Woodrow Wilson and the Roots of Modern Liberalism”

Fran Fawcett Peterson, writer

Paul C. Peterson, Coastal Carolina University emeritus

James Piereson, Ph.D., author of “Shattered Consensus: The Rise and Decline of America’s Postwar Political Order”

Julie Ponzi, editor and writer, American Greatness

Stephen B. Presser, Northwestern University, author of “Law Professors: Three Centuries of Shaping American Law (forthcoming)”

Frank Price, screenwriter and producer, former CEO Columbia Pictures, former president Universal Pictures

Mark Pulliam, lawyer and writer

Eric Rasmusen, University of Indiana, co-author of “Measuring Judicial Independence: The Political Economy of Judging in Japan”

Alfred Regnery, lawyer and author of “Upstream: The Ascendance of American Conservatism”

R.R. Reno, editor and author of “Resurrecting the Idea of a Christian Society”

D.N. Robinson, Oxford University, author of “The American Founding: Its Intellectual and Moral Framework”

Erik S. Root, Ph.D., Roger Bacon Academy, author of “All Honor to Jefferson?”

Milton Rosenberg, University of Chicago emeritus

Constance Rossum, University of La Verne, co-author of “Rehabilitating Rehabilitation”

Ralph A. Rossum, Claremont McKenna College, author of “Antonin Scalia’s Jurisprudence: Text and Tradition”

Ronald Rotunda, Chapman University, co-author of “Treatise on Constitutional Law” (6 volumes)

D. Brian Scarnecchia, Ave Maria University, author of “Bioethics, Law and Human Life Issues”

Lisa Schiffren, writer, former White House speechwriter

Harold See, Belmont University

Roger L. Simon, Academy Award-nominated screenwriter, co-founder PJ Media, author of “I Know Best: How Moral Narcissism Is Destroying Our Republic, If It Hasn’t Already”

S. Fred Singer, Ph.D, author of “Ecology in Action”

Scott Soames, University of Southern California, author of “The Analytic Tradition in Philosophy”

Don Surber, author of “Trump the Press”

Larry Schweikart, University of Dayton, retired, co-author of NY Times bestseller “A Patriot’s History of the United States”

Carol Swain, Vanderbilt University, author of “Be the People: A Call to Reclaim America’s Faith and Promise”

Dennis Teti, writer

Peter Thiel, co-founder of PayPal, author of “Zero to One: Notes on Startups, or How to Build the Future”

James Trefil, George Mason University, author of “The Encyclopedia of Science and Technology”

R. Emmett Tyrrell, Jr., editor and author of “The Death of Liberalism”

Jeffrey Wallin, co-author of “An Uncertain Legacy: Essays on the Pursuit of Liberty”

Bradley C.S. Watson, Saint Vincent College, author of “Living Constitution, Dying Faith: Progressivism and the New Science of Jurisprudence”

Robert Weissberg, University of Illinois emeritus, author of “Bad Students, Not Bad Schools”

Diana West, author of “The Death of the Grown-up”

Thomas G. West, author of “Vindicating the Founders”

Victor Williams, Chair, Lawyers and Law Professors for Trump

J. Eric Wise, lawyer and writer

S. Stanley Young, North Carolina State University

Scot J. Zentner, CSU San Bernardino, author of “Liberalism and Executive Power: Woodrow Wilson and the American Founders”

John Zmirak, Ph.D., author of “The Politically Incorrect Guide to Catholicism”